# Can ES6 arrow functions have their own lexical this?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this

```
function Person(){
  this.age = 0;

  setInterval(() => {
    this.age++; // this refers to the person object
  }, 1000);
}
```

But what if I want to access the "this" of the setInterval function, instead of the parent object. I know arrow functions don't have a lexical this of their own, but is there a way to circumvent this, other than writing a non-arrow function?

Comment: Think carefully, what is `this` of `setInterval` function, and put the answer to a comment below ...

Comment: @Teemu what will be the `this` of `setInterval`

Comment: @zabusa Waiting for hashris' answer ...

Comment: @Teemu In case of arrow functions, this refers to the scope of Person. In case of ES5 functions, this would refer to the scope of the setInterval function itself, not its parent. I want to know if an ES6 function can somehow have its own scope.

Comment: @hashris Yes, an ES6 `function` can…

Comment: @Bergi how so, doesn't it take the lexical scope of its parent?

Comment: You're now mixing scope and execution context. In a "traditional" function expression `this` would refer to `window`, or in the strict mode it would be `undefined`.

Comment: Trying to circumvent the nature of an arrow function to do what does a function, is just wrong. You have function and arrow function choose your pick and use it as you need.

Comment: AFAIK you can think of `() => {}` as `(function(){}).bind(this)`. Which hopefully explains why you can't change `this`. No matter what you do it has already been bound. It's like it made a new function that calls the original function with whatever `this` was at bind time. In fact you could implement `bind` something like `function bind(fn, context) { return function() { return fn.apply(context, arguments); }; }` in which you can see bind is making a closure that calls `fn` with `context`. That function is closed. You can't change `context` after calling `bind`.

Comment: *"I know arrow functions don't have a lexical this of their own"* It's exactly the other way round. Arrow functions are the only functions with "lexical `this`" , i.e. `this` is resolved lexically vs dynamically. https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-function-environment-records

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to circumvent this, other than writing a non-arrow function?

**No.**

The this value that is passed into an arrow function is ignored by it and not available in any form.

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: @Pau You mean why it is ignored? Because it's designed to. It doesn't have its own `this` that the value could be set for, precisely so that when you use the `this` keyword in the arrow function body it refers to the one of the parent scope.

Comment: I meant if there was something related to scope, anyway thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**No, the [arrow function does not possess a`this` variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)** (nor `argument`, `super` & `new.target`) so there is nothing to "circumvent" to.

An arrow function is designed to inherit lexical scope, if it *did* have its own `this`- it would interfere with its defining behavior.

Don't think about arrow functions as a nice shorthand for a regular function.

Instead, you should "read" arrow functions as:

> ...*execute these statements in the surrounding context*...

and

> ...*this function does **not** have the mental overhead of tracking which, of the [4 patterns of invocation, are being used to determine the value of`this`](https://howchoo.com/g/ztbjzjqwngq/javascript-function-invocation-and-this-with-examples)*)

Comment: Yea that's exactly how I was thinking of them. Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` of `setInterval()` = `window`.
If you have strict mode enabled in your script (something like `'use strict';` at the start of your script) it will be `undefined`. For all intents and purposes you might wish to use the global scope of `window`

You can rewrite your function to access window like this:

```
setInterval(() => {
    this.age++; // this refers to the person object
    window.something = this.age;
}, 1000);
```

Also, you're not saving the setInterval ID so you can't clear it when the object is obsolete. It will remain in memory causing you potential memory leaks

```
function Person(){
  this.age = 0;
  this.kill = function() {window.clearInterval(this.interval);};
  this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    this.age++; // this refers to the person object
  }, 1000);
}
```

So that when a Person is obsolete, you can kill() them, leaving no traces of them.