# Having problem with Array.map() in React when I try to print all array items in unordered list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, ecmascript-6, react-fullstack

Here is the code :

```
let count = 0;

function GenerateValue(tasks) {
    count += 1;
    let someValue = Math.random() * 10;
    tasks.push({key : count, value : someValue});
    console.log(tasks);
}

function RenderTasks() {
    const tasks = [];
    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={() => GenerateValue(tasks)}>Add New Item</button>
            <h1>List</h1>
            <ul>
                {<li key = {count}>{tasks.map((msg) => msg.value)}</li>}
                {/*tasks.map((msg) => <li key = {count}>{msg.value}</li>)*/}
            </ul>
        </>
    );
}
export default RenderTasks;
```

And here's the output :

[image: Output]

Now some explanation for my code :
This is just a testing program that I made when learning React. The code is simply generating a random number and adding it to an array named 'tasks'. Now I want to print all items of 'tasks' on screen in list form. And as you can see in the output, the items are being generated and added as well in the array (you can see that in console). But I'm unable to print them on screen. Now, I think there is something very simple and easy error that I'm missing but I'm tired of checking it over and over again, and would like your help. So please help me figure out what the problem is.

Also note that there is another line of code right below the one where I try to print the list items that I have commented. I have tried that too and it is not working either. Below is the output when I try that method :

[image]

I will wait for our kind-hearted community's response.

As for what I triedm it is already shown in the code. And since I was learning from w3schools, you can see that my commented line is exactly like their's in their React tutorial, but the funny thing is that it is working in their program but not in mine.

This is the line I'm talking about that is in my code :
`{tasks.map((msg) => <li key = {count}>{msg.value}</li>)}`

And this is the w3schools version for their own program :
`{cars.map((car) => <Car key={car.id} brand={car.brand} />)}`

You can also check their program here :
[Check the 'Keys' section.](https://www.w3schools.com/REACT/react_lists.asp)

Comment: The problem is that you're not handling component *state* correctly (or, really, at all). Nothing tells React that it should re-render your component when you click the button, because `tasks` is just a local variable, not a state member. See [the documentation](https://react.dev/learn/state-a-components-memory). Fair enough to miss this out as a beginner, but it's **very** well-covered in React tutorials, including the ones on the React website.

Comment: In whatever React tutorial(s) you're using, you've skipped a *fundamental* aspect of using React... *state*.  Just updating the values of variables doesn't trigger the component to re-render.  `tasks` should be a state value, and `GenerateValue` should update state with a new value.

Comment: Thanks for the response, everyone . I now understand my mistake, which was painfully obvious too. I knew something very basic was missing. But I have not read about hooks just yet. So I cannot use states in functional components. However, I have read about class components and their state object. But now I'm stuck in there too. I realize that I should be using the spread operator with setState() but I'm not sure how to do it. So now, if you can help me again with that, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-organized your code a bit to work as a functional component.
As others were commenting, you need to use state to re-render your components on updates. I removed *count* since .map allows for indexing.( you can add it back as a variable inside TaskFunction if you deem necessary )

W3 School's example works because they are not updating state. They have a list that is pre-set with values and render those values.

Lastly, your map function need to 'return' the element. As in the w3 school's example, map returns the Car component. So what you had was a little mixed up.

Hope this helps.

```js
function App() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = React.useState([])
  const generateValue=()=>{
    let someValue = Math.random() *10
    let newValue = {value: someValue}
    setTasks([...tasks, newValue])
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={()=>{generateValue()}}>Add New Item</button>
      <h1>List</h1>
      <ul>
        {tasks.map((task, index)=>(<li key={index}>{task.value}</li>))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(<App />)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

In a comment you ask to see the state example using the old style class components -

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    tasks: []
  }
  generateValue = () => {
    let someValue = Math.random() *10
    let newValue = {value: someValue}  
    this.setState({ tasks: [ ...this.state.tasks, newValue ] })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.generateValue}>Add New Item</button>
        <h1>List</h1>
        <ul>
          {this.state.tasks.map((task, index)=>(<li key={index}>{task.value}</li>))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(<App />)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Without [public class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields) -

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      tasks: []
    }
  }
  generateValue() {
    let someValue = Math.random() *10
    let newValue = {value: someValue}  
    this.setState({ tasks: [ ...this.state.tasks, newValue ] })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.generateValue.bind(this)}>Add New Item</button>
        <h1>List</h1>
        <ul>
          {this.state.tasks.map((task, index)=>(<li key={index}>{task.value}</li>))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(<App />)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. After reading other's comments, I understand I forgot about states. And I can see you have fixed that mistake in your code. However, I have not yet studied about the concept of hooks and hence cannot use states in functional components. However, I have read about class components and their state object. So, if you would be so generous as to show me how would I use setState() to update the 'tasks' array, I would be grateful. I think the way to go about it is to use the spread operator with setState() but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: @JayantVerma I added an example using old style class components. It's maybe not evident in a small example like this, but I suggest you learn hooks as they fit the React design pattern much better.

Comment: @Mulan Thanks for the answer. It's working perfectly. I tried this same solution yesterday and it didn't work. And it was because I was not using the arrow function for generateValue but traditional ones instead. Which throws a runtime exception that says: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setState')". And, I will most certainly study hooks very soon. Now that the issue is solved, can you elaborate on why the program worked when I use the arrow function but not when I use traditional ones. I think it's because they both handle 'this' differently. But that is all I know.

Comment: @JayantVerma there's a good chance you made a mistake. I provided another example above. Both JavaScript and React have evolved a lot over the years and unfortunately there's a lot of stuff you will have to learn about just to avoid using them. Classes and managing dynamic function scope (`Function.prototype.bind`) are among those things.

Comment: @Mulan, thank you very much for the answer. I'm now starting to understand how and why your code works correctly. Plus, thanks to you, I have also learned a bit about the bind() method. Though I don't think I know everything there is to know about it, I at least figured out its basic functionality. In my previous failed attempt, I didn't even use the bind method which caused an infinite loop of calling that function.

Comment: I'm delighted to help you. Before arrow functions, every `function() { ... }` introduce its own `this` and using `bind` (or `call`, or `apply`) was the primary means to manage the value of `this`. With arrow functions, `bind`, `call`, and `apply` are all but obsolete relics of the past. Amongst my other posts, I found [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73427754/633183) and [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17711245/633183) that may provide additional insight.